# how to access s3 bucket in airflow without giving connection string via admin -> connection UI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow-2.x

I would like the connect to aws s3 without making use of the Admin-> configuration UI of Airflow.
Can any one ,please let me know is there a way to do so in Apache Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to connect to AWS S3 without using the default s3 operator in Airflow, You can use the `PythonOperator` and make sure boto is added to the python dependencies which Airflow is using.

For installing boto you can use
`pip install boto3`

If you are using docker you have to add boto in the docker file.

```
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time




args = {
    'owner': 'airflow_default',
    'start_date': datetime(2022,6,6)
}

def s3_connect(ds, **kwargs):
    '''' Connect to s3 using Boto script '''
    s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-east-2',
    aws_access_key_id='mykey',
    aws_secret_access_key='mysecretkey'
    )
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)


def my_dummy_function():
    '''  Dummy function for doing nothing '''
    return 'dummy function test'

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_python_operator_without_s3', default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None)

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_context',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=s3_connect,
    dag=dag)

also_this =  PythonOperator(task_id="dummy_function", python_callable=my_dummy_function,dag= dag)

run_this>>also_this
```